# automatically generating serial keys with hemming distance in java using eclipse and MySql hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am working on a project, building a program for a chain of cinemas using java in eclipse and MySql as a database with hibernate.

As a part of it, I am trying to allow canceling purchases, and for that reason I want each purchase to have a serial key that can be used to track the canceled purchase.
But if the serial keys are a simple count++, then a simple mistake by a client might cancel an order by another client.

For that reason, I want the serial keys to having a minimum Hamming distance so mistakes like that cant happen.
I was wondering if there was a known way of doing this with either a java library or maybe something built into hibernate?

Comment: But i think when you use an id/serial key, regardless of the "distance" a attacker could guess it, too... i think you should be sure that only the user that creates the purchase can cancel it.

Comment: @pL4Gu33 Imagine a real cinema system, as a client you don't log in, so a serial key for your purchase is how you would cancel it.
And as for the distance, with as little as a hemming distance of 4 between key's the odds of actually getting a different key by accident are impossibly low.

Comment: *"getting a different key by accident are impossibly low."* pl4gu33 isn't talking about *accidentally* getting a key, but intentionally getting it. Just pick a random string that is long enough. Everybody does it that way (search for "validation token" in a search engine of your choice).